# AngularJS(1.1.5) infinite loop on not authorized response

Tags: grails, angularjs, spring-security

So, I have an application I wrote with Angular. It is essentially a SPA, except my login is done via traditional non ajax request. All that I want is to redirect the page (completely bypass the routes) to /logout when the server returns 401. I could set up an ajax based login, but frankly I don't see the benefit. Given that, if it is easier to do so - I would do whatever will get me past this insanely annoying hurdle that was INCREDIBLY simple with jQuery. Here is what I have that puts me into an infinite loop when I delete the authorization cookie:

```
var manageModule = angular.module('manageModule', ['ngResource']);

manageModule.config(function($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] =
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';


        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);


        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $window) {
            return {
                'responseError': function(rejection) {
                    var status = rejection.status;
                    if (status == 401) {
                        console.log('401 inside if');
                        $window.location.href = contextPath + '/logout';
                    }
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            }
        });


        $routeProvider
            .when('/majors', {
                templateUrl: contextPath+'/manage/majors',
                controller: ManageMajorsController
            })
            .when('/users', {
                templateUrl: contextPath+'/manage/users',
                controller: ManageUsersController
            })
            .when('/courses', {
                templateUrl: contextPath+'/manage/courses',
                controller: ManageCoursesController
            })
            .when('/notes', {
                templateUrl: contextPath+'/manage/notes',
                controller: ManageNotesController
            })
            .when('/manage', {
                templateUrl: contextPath+'/manage/majors',
                controller: ManageMajorsController
            });

});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

This seems to be somewhat new behavior, I remember it being in a redirect loop. Either way, here is what gets output to the console infinitely.

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=f.$$replace;if(!m||a!=f.absUrl())m++,\nc.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",f.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?f.$$parse(a):(d.url(f.absUrl(),b),i(a))});f.$$replace=!1;return m}; newVal: 15; oldVal: 14"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=f.$$replace;if(!m||a!=f.absUrl())m++,\nc.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",f.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?f.$$parse(a):(d.url(f.absUrl(),b),i(a))});f.$$replace=!1;return m}; newVal: 16; oldVal: 15"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=f.$$replace;if(!m||a!=f.absUrl())m++,\nc.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",f.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?f.$$parse(a):(d.url(f.absUrl(),b),i(a))});f.$$replace=!1;return m}; newVal: 17; oldVal: 16"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=f.$$replace;if(!m||a!=f.absUrl())m++,\nc.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",f.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?f.$$parse(a):(d.url(f.absUrl(),b),i(a))});f.$$replace=!1;return m}; newVal: 18; oldVal: 17"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=f.$$replace;if(!m||a!=f.absUrl())m++,\nc.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",f.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?f.$$parse(a):(d.url(f.absUrl(),b),i(a))});f.$$replace=!1;return m}; newVal: 19; oldVal: 18"]]
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Object.e.$digest (http://localhost:8080/MetroCredit/static/bundle-main_defer.js:91:135)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://localhost:8080/MetroCredit/static/bundle-main_defer.js:92:431)
    at j (http://localhost:8080/MetroCredit/static/bundle-main_defer.js:101:80)
    at r (http://localhost:8080/MetroCredit/static/bundle-main_defer.js:104:449)
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8080/MetroCredit/static/bundle-main_defer.js:106:90) bundle-main_defer.js:63
Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached.
```

Comment: When you say infinite loop, do you mean the angular digest cycle limit or does it actually loop forever somewhere.  If it is looping, do you see anything in the console (for example: '401 inside if')?  What happens when you try to pause javascript execution in the browser?  Where is the loop?  Is it a redirect loop?

Comment: I commented out my http interceptor code and the same thing actually happens.

Comment: Great.  I have seen this one before actually :)

Comment: Same here! :-( And it does not always happen, only some times. Weird!
Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same thing happens to me , it seems like spring security adds hash at the end of the url , angular tries to remove it but chrome returns it again, this causes a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417#issuecomment-18961232).

I have used this before in my controller when I didn't want to use Angular's routing at all:

```
// Abort Angular JS default location change handling.
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
  if (newUrl == $location.absUrl()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

For your case, it looks like you only want to bail out on certain URLs, so you may want/need to do some pattern matching in place of `newUrl == $location.absUrl()`.

This might not work perfectly for you since I wanted to avoid all of Angular's routing mechanisms, and I am not sure how compatible it is with newer versions.  I have used it with the Angular 1.0.x releases.

Comment: I was on 1.1.5 and I switched to 1.0.7 and I no longer get that infinite loop.

Comment: What I posted *should* kill all routing, which is why I said you would need to alter it to only call `event.preventDefault()` under certain conditions.